# running C# libraries inside another project

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code

I'm trying to get [this](https://github.com/jugglingcats/tachograph-reader/tree/net5) library to work inside my project. I've downloaded it to my documents folder and in the same documents folder I've created a new **C# console** app with just a `Program.cs` to try and run it. I can compile the library as far as I know.

Now, I've imported the project into my project using:

```
dotnet add C:/blabla/documents/tachograph-reader-test-code/tachograph-reader-test-code.csproj reference C:/blabla/documents/tachograph-reader/src/tachograph-reader-lib.csproj
```

and this worked just fine. As the following piece of code is added to my project file:

```
 <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\tachograph-reader\src\tachograph-reader-lib.csproj" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

Now for the life of me, I can't figure out how to use the library?

Intellisense does not see the library in any way. the `using` keyword doenst work either. De namespace should be `DataFileReader` but I cannot use it, and it won't compile.

By the way, I'm using **VS CODE** not vs studio.

So, how do I use such a library inside my project?

Comment: Can you open the application project in the repo, `tachograph-reader-core.csproj` ? Is there any differences regarding references between that and your project?

Comment: Well, now i'm completely lost. I've did as you requested. Ran restore. It compiled. Changed it back to the src/*.csproj and that works now as well... Intellisense still doesn't recognize it, so that's the next problem i'm going to solve but at least this works. thanks mate!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is **not in your project reference**. I guess you have to add these three **namespaces** as follow:

```
using System.IO;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
```

Your `Program.cs` should look like:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using DataFileReader;

namespace tachograph-reader-test-code
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            ...
        }

        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer. The problem is solved by now. Cannot tell you exactly what was wrong or what happend. For some reason unknown to me (most likely a dotnet restore somewhere) it started working. Any how, I used the namespaces already as you suggested, but that was not the issue. It just couldn't find the reference to the other project.